# How to get Drive items and filter by ContentType

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

In v4 Graph SDK, I could fetch drive items including ContentType. How to do it in v5?

```
 var allDocs = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].List.Items.Request().GetAsync();

 var files = allDocs.Where(d => !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("customfolder") && !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("folder"));
```

I can get allDocs fine, but they do not contain ContentType:

```
// Get the site's driveId
var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.GetAsync();
var siteDriveId = driveItem.Id;
// List children in the drive
var allDocs = await graphClient.Drives[siteDriveId].Items.GetAsync();
                
var files = allDocs.Value.Where(d => !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("customfolder") && !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("folder")); // <<< d.ContentType is null
```

Answer (score 0):

For v5, you are retrieving `driveItems` instead of `listItems`. Try to change
`Drives[siteDriveId].Items` to `Drives[siteDriveId].List.Items`

```
var allDocs = await graphClient.Drives[siteDriveId].List.Items.GetAsync();
var files = allDocs.Value.Where(d => !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("customfolder") && !d.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Equals("folder"));
```

Server side filtering by `contentType` should also work, but only case-sensitive.

```
var files = await graphClient.Drives[siteDriveId].List.Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "contentType/name ne 'customfolder' and contentType/name ne 'folder'";
});
```